# Cannot move to another view, Error Cannot add text nodes as direct child of an aggregation

Tags: html, xml, sapui5

I develop a Split App. There is a List Item, if I click on an item, it will navigate to another view. But it can not navigate and give error

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot add text nodes as direct child of an aggregation. For adding text to an aggregation, a surrounding html tag is needed
```

The error points to this.getRouter().navTo(...) in the controller. Can someone tell me where I'm wrong? Thank you

This is the onSelect event to navigate

```
onSelect : function(oEvent) {
var oContext = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext("Z5"));
var oTransferData = this.createTransferData(oContext);

if(this.transferData === undefined) {
    this.transferData = new JSONModel();
}
this.transferData.setData(oTransferData);
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(
    this.transferData,
    "StockFrom"
);

this.getRouter().navTo(
    "to", 
    {
        CODE : oTransferData.CODE,
        WERKS : oTransferData.WERKS
    });}
```

I have target and route in manifest.json

```
"routes": [ {
    "pattern": "StockFrom/Code={CODE}/Location/Site={WERKS}",
    "name": "to",
    "target": "stockTo"
},

"targets":
    "stockTo": {
        "viewName": "stockTo",
        "viewLevel": 2
    },
```

This is target view stockTo.view.xml

```
<mvc:View controllerName="Z5.controller.stockTo" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m">
<App>
    <pages>
        <Page>
            <content>
                <core:Fragment fragmentName="Z5.view.fragment.stockTo.content" type="XML"/>
            </content>
            <footer>
                <core:Fragment fragmentName="Z5.view.fragment.stockTo.footer" type="XML"/>
            </footer>
        </Page>
    </pages>
</App>
```

And 2 fragments of it

content.fragment.xml

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
<Table
    ...
>
    <headerToolbar>
        ...
    </headerToolbar>
    <columns>
        <Column>
            <Label text="Plant" />
        </Column>
        <Column>            
            <Label text="Stock Quantity}" />
        </Column>            
        <Column hAlign="Right">
            <Label text="D. Quantity}" />
        </Column>           
    </columns>
</Table>
```

and footer.fragment.xml

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
<Toolbar width="100%">
    <HBox width="100%" alignItems="Start" justifyContent="End">
        <Button
            ...
        />
    </HBox>
</Toolbar>
```

Comment: I think this patter is not correct: `StockFrom/Code={CODE}/Location/Site={WERKS}`. Try `"StockFrom/{CODE}/Location/{WERKS}"`

Comment: thanks but that's not the case

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the *target view* and found an *uninvited guest (character)*, somehow my friend accidental placed it there.
If *Web IDE* can give a warning in the first place.